# How to correctly use DataBinding in a PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am using data binding and I am extending a `PagerAdapter`. What I do not understand is how to inflate the view while stil keeping the variables already bound in the activity.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        IPage page = pages[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        try {
            // how to inflate? the DataBindingUtil way just terribly crashes
            /*ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(inflater, page.getTargetViewId(), collection, false).getRoot();  
            */
            ViewGroup layout = inflater.inflate(page.getTargetViewId(), collection, false);

            collection.addView(layout);
            page.onCreate(layout, position);

            return layout;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "inflatinve page " + position + " failed!" , e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

DataBindingUtil crashes badly and when I pass the binding the method binding#inflate does not support the view group.

Update 1: It seems that the binding result of `DataBindingUtil.inflate(...)` is always null.

Comment: just having that said I use JavaFX and JavaFXPorts now where the UI designer and binding works way better. yeah therefore there are other issues ...